# Strange post request behaviour Java to Java call

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am making a server to server post request. It reaches destination alternatively. 
First time it works, second time it fails with error response 501 and works again if retry for third time.

I checked access logs and found that few of my post parameters are getting attached to the method name whenever it fails like :

```
mount=100&pg=itz&mid=DEFAULT_YAT_TP&respc=4010POST
```

These variables arepart of the post request which is supposed to get fired.

I checked tomcat configuration as well, everything seems to be fine.

I appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem.

Problem is that request buffer of previous post request doesnt gets clears somehow and gets prepend to stream of bytes of new Post request

Solution is to stop buffering of request which will prevent such strange behaviours in cases of request buffer not getting flushed properly.
This can be achieved by enabling a property to post method as :

```
postMethod.setContentChunked(true);
```

After making the changes havent experienced the issue again.